# How can I control the class name rendered with use of MvcSiteMap().Menu()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

When using Nuget package "MvcSitemapProvider Mvc5", I have learned to use the following technique when I want to show only a specific branch of the overall sitemap.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "Mammals" });
```

While the correct content is rendered, an unfortunate site-effect is that a class name is defined along with the rendered list. I call this unfortunate because Bootstrap renders this as a menu by virtue of the ID and class names. I want it to be a simple unstyled list.

My question is whether there is a way to override this so that I can have the unordered list without any ID or class names -- or perhaps assign names of my choosing?

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li>
   @* sitemap content... *@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible approach, but I present it with caution because it changes an existing helper. Since I'm not going to use the MVC Sitemap Provider for horizontal menus, this will suit my purposes.

I found the file "MenuHelperModel.cshtml" in `Views > Shared > DisplayTemplates` and made this change:

> ```
> @*
>     This is the original. I took this out so it wouldn't be renderd as a menu.
>     <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
>     This is adapted so that I can show parts of the sitemap as
>          plain lists and not as menus.
> *@
> <ul>
>     @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
>     {
>         <li>
>             @Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
>             @if (node.Children.Any())
>             {
>                 @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
>             }
>         </li>
>     }
> </ul>
> ```